# GitHub Pages で一部の画像だけ表示されない

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

以下です。よろしければご回答のほど、よろしくお願いいたします・・！

#### 聞きたいこと

GitHub Pagesにて公開したページにて、imgフォルダ内の一部の画像のみ表示されない。

#### 対象URL

https://yukinoshita1103.github.io/leopaquiz/quiz.html

#### 詳細

クイズのWebアプリ。
選択肢として、imgディレクトリに置いた画像をランダムに表示させたいです。
しかし、imgディレクトリにある、
「スーパーマックスノー」
「トレンパーアルビノ」
「ハイポタンジェリン」
「ブレイジングブリザード」
のみが404となり、表示されません。

ローカルでの挙動確認は確認済みで、画像の上げ直し、ファイル名をjsファイルの文言をコピペしてリネームも済みです。
相対パスになっていないことも確認済みです。

画像ファイルの名前が日本語ですが、画像名を英語に変えるのは、現状難し意図考えております。画像名とjsの配列のkeyを同じにしており、そこが同値かどうかで正誤判定しているため。

#### ファイル内容

GitHub

https://github.com/yukinoshita1103/leopaquiz

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="ja">   <head>
    <meta charaset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>レオパモルフ検定</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="stylesheet.css"
      media="screen"
    />   </head>   <body>
    <!-- 問題 -->
    <div>
      Q<span id="question-number"></span>：<span id="question-molf-name"></span
      >はどっち？
    </div>
    <!-- 画像を正解／不正解1枚ずつ -->
    <div class="flex">
      <div id="left" onclick="buttonClickLeft(this.id)">aaa</div>
      <div id="right" onclick="buttonClickRight(this.id)">aaa</div>
    </div>
    <!-- 正誤判定 -->
    <div id="marubatsu"></div>
    <!-- タイマー -->
    <div class="timer-wrap">
      <span>
        残り
        <span id="timer-text"></span>
        秒
      </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Timer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Question.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Result.js"></script>   </body> </html>
```

JavaScript

```
全モルフを格納
let molfArray = [
  "ハイイエロー",
  "スーパーマックスノー",
  "エメリン",
  "トレンパーアルビノ",
  "ハイポタンジェリン",
  "ブレイジングブリザード",
  "レモンフロスト",
  "バンディット",
  "ギャラクシー",
  "ブラックナイト",
];

// 問題番号をインクリメントする関数を作る。
function increment() {
  questionNumber++;
  questionNumberElement.innerText = questionNumber;
}

// 問題文をランダムに作成する関数を作る。
function molfQuestion() {
  imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
  molfQuestionName = molfArray[imageNumber];
  questionElement.innerText = molfQuestionName;
}

// 選択肢がランダムで2枚表示され、正誤判定する関数を作る。
function molfAnswer() {
  // 正解のモルフを用意する。
  imageMolf = '<img src="image/' + molfQuestionName + '.jpg">';
  // 不正解のモルフを用意する。
  do {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
  } while (i === imageNumber);
  notImageNumber = i;
  notImageMolf = '<img src="image/' + molfArray[notImageNumber] + '.jpg">';
  // 正解と不正解を格納した配列を用意する。
  optionArray = [];
  optionArray[0] = imageMolf;
  optionArray[1] = notImageMolf;
  // 正解と不正解をランダムにエレメントに格納する。
  c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  do {
    d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  } while (c === d);
  a = c;
  b = d;
  imageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[a];
  notImageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[b];
  // 左右の画像名を代入
  optionA = optionArray[a]
    .replace('<img src="image/', "")
    .replace('.jpg">', "");
  optionB = optionArray[b]
    .replace('<img src="image/', "")
    .replace('.jpg">', "");
}

// 何問目かを表示する。

let questionNumber = 1;
let questionNumberElement = document.getElementById("question-number");
questionNumberElement.innerText = questionNumber;

// 問題文をランダムに作成。

let imageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
let molfQuestionName = molfArray[imageNumber];
let questionElement = document.getElementById("question-molf-name");
questionElement.innerText = molfQuestionName;

// 正解のモルフを用意する。

let imageElement = document.getElementById("left");
let imageMolf = '<img src="image/' + molfQuestionName + '.jpg">';
// imageElement.innerHTML = imageMolf;

// 不正解のモルフを用意する。

do {
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * molfArray.length);
} while (i === imageNumber);
let notImageNumber = i;
let notImageElement = document.getElementById("right");
let notImageMolf = '<img src="image/' + molfArray[notImageNumber] + '.jpg">';
// notImageElement.innerHTML = notImageMolf;

// 正解と不正解を格納した配列を用意する。

let optionArray = [];
optionArray[0] = imageMolf;
optionArray[1] = notImageMolf;

// 正解と不正解をランダムにエレメントに格納する。

c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
do {
  d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
} while (c === d);

a = c;
b = d;

imageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[a];
notImageElement.innerHTML = optionArray[b];

// 左右の画像名を代入

let optionA = optionArray[a]
  .replace('<img src="image/', "")
  .replace('.jpg">', "");
let optionB = optionArray[b]
  .replace('<img src="image/', "")
  .replace('.jpg">', "");

// 左の画像をクリックして、正誤ごとに処理を行う。

function buttonClickLeft() {
  if (optionA === molfQuestionName) {
    console.log("正解");
    // 正解と表示される。
    let marubatsuElement = document.getElementById("marubatsu");
    marubatsuElement.innerText = "正解だよん";
    // 正解表示のN秒後、正解という表示が非表示になる。
    value = "";
    setTimeout(() => {
      marubatsuElement.innerText = value;
    }, 300);
    // 正解表示のN秒後、問題番号がインクリメントされる。
    setTimeout(increment, 300);
    //  正解表示のN秒後、問題名がランダムに表示される関数を表示。
    setTimeout(molfQuestion, 300);
    //  正解表示の2秒後、選択肢がランダムで2枚表示され、正誤判定する関数を利用。
    setTimeout(molfAnswer, 300);
    //  正解表示のN秒後、タイマーがリセットされる。
    setTimeout(() => {
      originalTime = 999;
      timerElement.innerText = originalTime;
    }, 300);
  } else {
    console.log("不正解");
    // 不正解と表示される。
    let marubatsuElement = document.getElementById("marubatsu");
    marubatsuElement.innerText = "間違いじゃぼけ";
    // 得点を用意する。
    let scr = questionNumber - 1;
    console.log(scr);
    window.localStorage.setItem("result", scr);
    // 不正解表示のN秒後、ページが遷移される。
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "./consequence.html";
    }, 300);
  }
}

// 右をクリックして、正解の場合、正解とログする。

function buttonClickRight() {
  if (optionB === molfQuestionName) {
    console.log("正解");
    // 正解と表示される。
    let marubatsuElement = document.getElementById("marubatsu");
    marubatsuElement.innerText = "正解だよん";
    // 正解表示のN秒後、正解という表示が非表示になる。
    value = "";
    setTimeout(function () {
      marubatsuElement.innerText = value;
    }, 300);
    // 正解表示の2秒後、問題番号がインクリメントされる。
    setTimeout(increment, 300);
    //  正解表示の2秒後、問題名がランダムに表示される関数を表示。
    setTimeout(molfQuestion, 300);
    //  正解表示の2秒後、選択肢がランダムで2枚表示され、正誤判定する関数を利用。
    setTimeout(molfAnswer, 300);
    //  正解表示のN秒後、タイマーがリセットされる。
    setTimeout(() => {
      originalTime = 999;
      timerElement.innerText = originalTime;
    }, 300);
  } else {
    console.log("不正解");
    // 不正解と表示される。
    let marubatsuElement = document.getElementById("marubatsu");
    marubatsuElement.innerText = "間違いじゃぼけ";
    // 得点を用意する。
    let scr = questionNumber - 1;
    console.log(scr);
    window.localStorage.setItem("result", scr);
    // 不正解表示のN秒後、ページが遷移される。
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "./consequence.html";
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アクセスする日本語パスととWebサーバーの提供パスが実際は違うためエラーとなっています。
例として「スーパーマックスノー」の画像URLです

エラー
https://yukinoshita1103.github.io/leopaquiz/image/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC.jpg

成功
https://yukinoshita1103.github.io/leopaquiz/image/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8F%E3%82%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC.jpg

見た目上一緒ですが「パ」の文字がデータ的には違います。
パのハと濁点を一緒のデータとするか別々の文字として管理するかで違いがでています。（詳しくはUnicode正規化のキーワードで調べてみてください）

今回は以下のサイトで `スーパーマックスノー` の文字を入力し、非正規化の文字をコピーすると成功しました。`molfArray` 内の日本語を一度変換すれば成功するのではないかと思います
https://dencode.com/ja/string/unicode-normalization

Comment: ありがとうございます！！
初見の知識だったので勉強になりました！

ただ、molfArray内の日本語を、全て正規化／非正規化（互換含）しても、現状の正規化を行っても、一部の画像が表示できず困っています。

具体的には、
①https://dencode.com/ja/string/unicode-normalization　で全て非正規化を行う
→  "バンディット", "ギャラクシー","ブラックナイト",　が表示されない。
②①で表示されないもののみ、その他の物に変換してみる
→変わらず、非表示。
③https://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=7635　で全て変換してみる。
→「スーパーマックスノー」「トレンパーアルビノ」「ハイポタンジェリン」「ブレイジングブリザード」が非表示となる。

です。
お手数ですが、ヒントのみでもよろしいので、ご教示いただけますと幸いです・・！

Comment: 考えられる可能性としてはファイル名のほうの正規化方式が混じってるということですね。 ファイル名とJS内の文字をそれぞれ変換後のコピペで保存することを試してみてください。